# TypeError: input[key - 1].value is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have seven `td`s in my table, and I use `getElementsByTagName()` method to get all `input`s and perform validation that detects if the numbers are entered in low to high order. But when I try, Firebug shows

```
TypeError: input[key - 1].value is undefined
```

What should I do?

```
this.identificador1 = $(id_1).get(0);
this.input_array = this.identificador1.getElementsByTagName('input');
var input = this.input_array;

$.each(this.input_array, function(key, value) {
    if (input[key-1].value < input[key].value){
        …
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the `-1` for?

Comment: @IMSoP im use the -1 for get the number before and use it validate if this is less than the forward.

Comment: In the first iteration, `key` has the value `0`, so you are trying to access `input[-1]`, which does not exist.

Comment: I believe @IMSoP means "what's input[-1] for", there is no -1 index in keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare each member of the array to the previous member… including the *first* member which doesn't have a previous one.

Skip the test when the key is `0`.

```
 $.each(this.input_array,function(key,value){
        if (key === 0) {
            return;
        }            
        if(input[key-1].value < input[key].value){
        }       
    });
```